# Accessing crystal reports in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I need to access a Crystal Report that is deployed on a Crystal Report server.

I want to display this report on my ASP.NET page. However, I don't want to include the report file in my project. I need to use the report file deployed on crystal report server.

Can you please guide me on how to do this?

Comment: Why did you label this with Ruby/Python? Please remove those tags.

Comment: I am a new to this website. I didnt get what exactly is the tag? so copy pasted the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ReportDocument.Load(<filePath>, OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy)
```